# Check Excel File Sheet for missing columns

Tags: vb.net, excel, ssis, excel-2010, vb.net-2010

I have an ssis package which takes an excel file and imports it, but if any of the columns in the sheet are missing then the import fails.

Im trying to write some code to check the column header in a sheet to make sure it contains a set list of columns, it doesn't need to check if there in the correct order, as long as they exist.

The code i have so far is as follows

```
Dim strFile As String

strFile = Dts.Variables("User::found_file").Value.ToString

Dim xlConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & _
      strFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES"""
Dim xlConnection As New OleDbConnection(xlConnectionString)
xlConnection.Open()

Dim tablesInFile As DataTable = xlConnection.GetSchema("TABLES")

Dim currentTable As String
Dim columnsInTable As DataTable
Dim columnRestrictions(3) As String
Dim columnInTable As DataRow
Dim currentColumn As String

For Each tableInFile As DataRow In tablesInFile.Rows

    currentTable = tableInFile.Item("TABLE_NAME").ToString


    'tray header
    If currentTable = "'Tray Header$'" Then
        columnRestrictions(2) = currentTable
        columnsInTable = xlConnection.GetSchema("COLUMNS", columnRestrictions)

     end if  
next
```

I need an easy way of checking all the columns to make sure they all exists, without having to do a loop and checking each one, one at a time.

I need it to flag a failure boolean as true if a column is missing.

The columns the 'tray header' sheet contains are trayid, trayname, description, quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `SELECT` to verify your file:

```
    Dim blnMissingColumns As Boolean = False

    Dim cmdTest As OleDbCommand = xlConnection.CreateCommand
    cmdTest.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 trayid, trayname, description, quantity FROM [Tray Header$]"

    Try
        cmdTest.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If TypeOf ex Is OleDbException Then
            If CType(ex, OleDbException).ErrorCode = -2147217904 Then
                blnMissingColumns = True
            End If
        End If
    End Try

    cmdTest.Dispose()
```